# Passing UUID along with MPI's message

Tags: mpi

Is there any way that I can pass uuid_t along with MPI's message by using MPI_Pack()? Because as I know MPI does not support that particular datatype.

Answer (score 0):

Got it, I can just pass it with MPI_datatype of MPI_CHAR with length of string I want to send. For example:

```
MPI_Unpack(buffer, bufsize, &pos, &msg->sender_uuid, 37, MPI_CHAR, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

while 37 is string length.

Comment: Do not use `MPI_CHAR` for binary data. Rather, use `MPI_BYTE`. Using `MPI_CHAR` might result in data conversion on certain platforms.